# Proof for an increasing sequence

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I wondered if you could help with this question.

Suppose that $(b_n)$ is an increasing sequence, bounded above by $B$. Thus $b_n \to b$ as $n \to \infty$ for some $b$. Show that $b \le B$.

Thank you :)

Comment: What is $B$?${}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $b > B$. Let us denote $\epsilon := b - B > 0$. By the definition of convergence, there is $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $|b_n-b|<\epsilon$. But then $b_n > b + \epsilon = B$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$|a_n| \leq B$ all $n$. Since it is convergent we can pass to the limit and thus $b = \lim b_n \leq \lim B = B $

Answer (score 0):

Suppose otherwise, i.e. $b> B$. By definition of limit for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $|b_n-b| < \epsilon$.

Take $\epsilon = \frac{b-B}{2} > 0$. Then there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $|b_n-b| < \frac{b-B}{2}$. But $|b_n - b| = b - b_n \geq b-B$. Contradiction.